# Text on an image with vignette effect CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a page banner which is an image with text over it. There are two things I am facing trouble with two things.

1. I need a smooth vignette effect on these images so that the text is clearly visible. I have tried the following but am not happy with the end result. I would like to get something as shown in the following image which shows a kind of smooth transition.
2. The text hides below the vignette effect. I tried using `z-index` but it does not work.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

#page-banner img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 48vh;
}

#page-banner .vignette:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 20em 5em 15em black;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 20em 5em 15em black;
  box-shadow: inset 20em 5em 15em black;
  z-index: 0;
}

#page-banner .text {
  width: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

#page-banner .text-over-image {
  position: relative;
}

#page-banner .text-over-image p {
  font-size: 60px;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 15%;
  right: 45%;
  transform: translate(-10%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<section id="page-banner">
  <div class="text-over-image vignette">
    <img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/5117570.jpg">
    <div class="text">
      <p>I am trying to learn adding vignette to images</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need change `z-index: 1` to `#page-banner .text-over-image p` to show the text.

To simulate smooth effect I put an opacity property.

If you want a really smooth effecty try change your font or use `font-smooth` but this feature is non-standard:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-smooth

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

#page-banner img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 48vh;
}

#page-banner .vignette:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 20em 5em 15em black;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 20em 5em 15em black;
  box-shadow: inset 20em 5em 15em black;
  z-index: 0;
}

#page-banner .text {
  width: 50%;
  right: 50%;
}

#page-banner .text-over-image {
  position: relative;
}

#page-banner .text-over-image p {
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.88;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 15%;
  right: 45%;
  transform: translate(-10%, -50%);
  animation: fadeIn 8s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    left: 13%;
    opacity: 0.69;
    color: white;
    
  }
  to {
    left: 18%;
    opacity: 0.88;
    color: whitesmoke;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px gray;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="page-banner">
  <div class="text-over-image vignette">
    <img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/5117570.jpg">
    <div class="text">
      <p>I am trying to learn adding vignette to images</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

##### Update:

I put an animation suggestion using `@keyframes` alternating:

- `opacity`, `left` and `text-shadow` values in `8s`

---

```
@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    left: 16%;
    opacity: 0.69;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px whitesmoke;
  }
  to {
    left: 18%;
    opacity: 0.88;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px gray;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any quick way to gradually decrease the opacity of the vignette effect moving from left to right?

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you used:

```
#page-banner .vignette::after
```

but you could just use:

```
#page-banner .vignette::before
```

instead.

That would position the `pseudo-element` *underneath* the content of `.vignette`, rather than over the top of it.

---

**Working Example:**

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

#page-banner img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}

#page-banner .vignette::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: inset 20em 5em 15em black;
  z-index: 0;
}

#page-banner .text {
  width: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

#page-banner .text-over-image {
  position: relative;
}

#page-banner .text-over-image p {
  font-size: 60px;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 15%;
  right: 45%;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transform: translate(-10%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<section id="page-banner">
  <div class="text-over-image vignette">
    <img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/5117570.jpg">
    <div class="text">
      <p>I am trying to learn adding vignette to images</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

Dont' use box-shadow. Instead give your `::after` this:

```
background: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.50);
```

then give your text `z-index = 1;`

Just play with your color's alpha to get the desired look.

Comment: That's not going to create a vignette, all that's doing is overlaying the color black with an alpha of 50% on the entire image. If you apply it to his code and change the alpha value to 1, all you'll see is black under the text.